# Stopping navigation bar from scrolling with table

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6, xcode4.3

I have a `UITableViewController` which successfully lists in the table view data fetched from a CoreData entity.

I want to have a navigation bar at the top with a couple of buttons to navigate around, but when I add the navigation bar it appears to sit inside the table, bellow any listings, and therefore scrolls wit the table when flicking through the table list.

As it is a `UITableViewController` I cannot make the table area smaller it seems and so I have no idea how to add the navigation bar outside of the table.

Any advise on how to make the fix the navigation bar in place so that it does not move.

Here is the code use to set the navigation bar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

 UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 1024,44)];
 UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Observation details"];
 [navBar pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:NO];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backButton)];
navItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
UIBarButtonItem *detailsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Observation Details" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(detailsButton)];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = detailsButton;
 [self.view addSubview:navBar];
}
```

Comment: Are you using Interface builder?

Comment: Using a storyboard?? Should I be doing this programmatically?

Comment: How did you add that navigation bar and what type of UI item is it? The standard navigation bar as provided by the system should not scroll at all.

Comment: @Hermann Yes, a navigation bar is a view and if you use a view as headerView of any table it will scroll with the table.

Comment: I have tried dragging it and writing it in programmatically. Either way it sits in the table and therefore scrolls.

Comment: @Gabriel, yes that is right. But then it is not "provide by the system". Of course you can create your own UINavigationBar items and add one to each custom cell and section header views and cell header views etc. pp. And that is exactly why I asked Richard for details. And now that he shared some relevant code we can really help a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't drag the navigation bar and drop on the table view. That way you are setting that view (a navigation bar) as the header of the table view.

To do what you are trying to do, the easiest way is to use a navigation controller with the table view as its rootTableView.

```
myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVC];

[self presentViewController:myNavController ...
```

You can also use a navigation bar without a navigation controller. For that, you have to set a View with a navigation controller at the top and a table view filling the rest of the view.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths: Post the code how you are doing it programmatically.

Comment: @Richard if you are using Story Board, you only have to include a navigation controller. That is really simple. If you want to do it programmatically, you have to declare a variable or property to retain the navigation controller. I'm to edit my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you see the response above. I have a Nav Controller now in which displays the table but still can't get the navigation bar to behave!

Comment: EUREKA - so simple in the end. Added the Navigation Controller, segued to the Navigation view, added the code for filling the table to the Table view and it worked first time. THANK YOU SO MUCH - I have been messing with this for months!!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. I try to describe the one of which I believe it is easiest based on what I guess is your current level of experience.

Create a new empty view with a separate view controller. 
Add two subviews to that view of the type container view. These views are designed to carry views that have their own view controllers. One of these containers is on top and has the size of the navigation bar and contains the navigation bar etc. 
For that one you could create a separate view controller. However, I see no reason why that could not be the same view controller. (File's owner in IB)
It may well be a separate instance/class. That is up to you.

The remaining view is occupied by the second container view. This one contains a `UITableView` for which a `UITableViewController` (-subclass) is the File's Owner.

Unless you are more familiar with the view hierarchy and view controller hierarchy you should not break with the pattern (as given by default sceleton code and tutorials etc.) of having a 1:1 relation between table view controlers and table views. A `UITableViewController` has a `view` property as every UIViewController has. But for a `UITableViewController` that must be a `UITableView` and nothing else. The standard `UITableViewController` is not capable of dealing with a `UIView` as `view` property that contains a table view and other views as siblings. Plus it is not a good idea of adding more subviews to the table view with respect to its scrolling behaviour etc.

By separating them you can deal with the table and still take examples straigt of tutorial code plus you can have a navigation bar on top that is not influenced by the table at all.

However, I should mention that you could get all of this much easier by using a proper navigation controller. That would bring in your navigation bar for free. You must have good rasons for not doing so.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you have put into this - thank you. I am trying the Navigation Controller method as everyone is saying it is so simple. I have the got the table view working but for some reason the navigation bar does not show at all when the app is run. I am new to navigation controllers and I am not sure of the need for the two views (one navigation and one table). I am reading up on it but getting nowhere. Very poor internet here means no video access either. Anyhow, might there be some simple reason why the navigation bar does not show?

Comment: I have noticed now that it is as soon as I link up the table to a button from the previous view using a segue the navigation bar on the table view just disappears!!

Comment: Really appreciate your help. See below.

Comment: Apologies for the late anwser. Right, you bring a navigation conroller in which displays your first view controller and it will care for the navigation bar. Your part of the view, natrually, gets a bit smaller by the size of the bar. As long as you use push segues, a new navigation bar will appear always with the title of the current navigation view (if any). And the back button will carry the name of the previos view controller, unless you change that. You only need one navigation controller. If you need to access it, use self.navigationController from any view controller.